# How to add all the elements of an int[] to a StringBuilder using a stream, adding extra space to each of the element

Tags: java, java-stream, stringbuilder

I am trying to add all the elements of an `int` array `brr` into a `StringBuilder` `res` using the following code:

```java
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

Arrays.stream(brr).forEach(res::append);
```

I want the `StringBuilder` to be:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

However, it is actually:

```
012345
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the trailing space, you can do this

```java
Arrays.stream(brr).forEach(i -> res.append(i).append(" "));
```

You can trim the string if you don't want to print the trailing space

```java
System.out.println(res.toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 3):

If using a StringBuilder is not a requirement, then you could do as follows.

Calling `Arrays.stream()` will return an `IntStream`. Using `mapToObj` with `String::valueOf` as the *mapper* will convert the *primitive int* to a String. This will return a `Stream<String>`. Finally, using `Collectors.joining`, we can concatenate the individual string elements of the stream with a space.

```
 String result = Arrays.stream(a)
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

One-liner:

```java
String.join ( 
    " " , 
    Arrays.stream ( ints ).mapToObj ( String :: valueOf ).toArray ( String[] :: new ) 
)
```

> 0 1 2 3 4 5

## Details

Make some sample data.

```
int[] ints = IntStream.rangeClosed ( 0 , 5 ).toArray ( );
```

Convert each `int` primitive value to text, each piece of text being a single character, a `String`-based version of our number. Collect these `String` objects into an array.

```
String[] strings = Arrays.stream ( ints ).mapToObj ( String :: valueOf ).toArray ( String[] :: new );
```

Join the strings in that array together, separated on the interior only by a SPACE character. No trailing SPACE, a convenient benefit of [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)).

```
String result = String.join ( " " , strings );
```

Put that all together.

```java
int[] ints = IntStream.rangeClosed ( 0 , 5 ).toArray ( );
String[] strings = Arrays.stream ( ints ).mapToObj ( String :: valueOf ).toArray ( String[] :: new );
String result = String.join ( " " , strings );
System.out.println ( "result = " + result );
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Wp4Kcj).

> result = 0 1 2 3 4 5